# Auto hide bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I want to hide automatically the Bootstrap popovers after a few seconds.
When the user hovers over a control, the popover must be displayed, but if the user doesn't move the mouse pointer, this popover must be hidden automatically after few seconds.

That is important because in a mobile phone or tablet when the user taps a control, the popover is displayed, and the focus remains on the same control while the user types something, with the popover hindering it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*Note: This solution was written for Bootstrap 3.*

This works, though there may be a more efficient method:

```js
$('.pop').popover().click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.pop').popover('hide');
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="pop" data-original-title="My popover" data-content="Isn't it great?">Click me</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Bqq7C/27/

Comment: I dont think, this will work perfectly when multiple popover elements on the same page. The problem is when first popover opens up, as in the code it will hide others. but when one open and you opens the second, the first ones timeout will execute and it will close the second one immediately upon opening since the code is to hide all popovers after 2 second. I faced that situation.

Comment: @sforsandeep You just need to add an intermediate variable pointing to your original jQuery object http://jsfiddle.net/franverona/zPdX9/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work very well, for a couple of reasons. 1) This is not on hover. 2) When it disappears, you have to click once to reset it, and then click a second time to activate it. 3) It doesn't remain up while the cursor is moving within the popup display.

Comment: thought this answer is accepted it misses one key information!! you have to add the trigger option while initializing popover .. {trigger:"manual"} .. otherwise the bootstraps attaches an onclick event to which causes the issue of two click required after first use .. following should is a proposed solution ....` $("#element").popover({trigger:"manual"}).click(function(){
          var pop = $(this);
          pop.popover("show")
          pop.on('shown.bs.popover',function(){
            setTimeout(function(){pop.popover("hide")},2200);
          })
      })`

Comment: @limplash, maybe that wasn't a concern with Bootstrap 2 or 3. Are you referring to Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @isherwood .. yes I am talking about Bootstrap 4 ... and i guess you are right it wasn't a concern ... but i guess my comment can serve for current users of bootstrap 4

Comment: sorry, this did not work for me, with bootstrap 4.3.1. i didn't want to down vote, but i accept [the solution at]  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28899537/4444742)

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer works just fine, but here's a more bootstrap approach:

**Original answer**

```
$('.pop').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    var $pop = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $pop.popover('hide');
    }, 2000);
});
```

---

**Update from limplash**

> This answer misses one key information!! you have to add the trigger option while initializing popover .. {trigger:"manual"} .. otherwise the bootstraps attaches an onclick event to which causes the issue of two click required after first use .. following should is a proposed solution

```
$("#element").popover({ trigger:"manual" }).click(function() { 
  var pop = $(this); 
  pop.popover("show") 
  pop.on('shown.bs.popover',function() { 
   setTimeout(function() {
    pop.popover("hide")}, 2200); 
  }) 
})
```

Comment: This is great, but after the popover is auto closed it takes two clicks to get it open again.  I think that the popover still thinks it is open, any fix for this?

Comment: @NateBunney, yes I also noticed it. The solution is to destroy the popover and reinitialise. I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: This answer misses one key information!! you have to add the trigger option while initializing popover .. {trigger:"manual"} .. otherwise the bootstraps attaches an onclick event to which causes the issue of two click required after first use .. following should is a proposed solution ....`$("#element").popover({trigger:"manual"}).click(function(){ var pop = $(this); pop.popover("show") pop.on('shown.bs.popover',function(){ setTimeout(function(){pop.popover("hide")},2200); }) })`

Comment: limplash's solution works like charm. Ty very much for that!

Answer (score 5):

You could also add your own new data-attribute to your popovers as such:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"][data-timeout]').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    this_popover = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        this_popover.popover('hide');
    }, $(this).data("timeout"));
});
```

Now you could use

```
<span 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    data-timeout="2000" 
    title="A title" 
    data-content="Some explanatory text">
    Your text
</span>
```

and the popover disappears after being shown the number of milliseconds you specified in data-timeout.

Comment: don't forget that "on" is better to have the filter to support changing UI - my 2 cents

$(document).on('shown.bs.popover', '[data-toggle="popover"][data-timeout]', function() {
    this_popover = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        this_popover.popover('hide');
    }, $(this).data("timeout"));
});