# Hide Bootstrap popover after a delay

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I already check out this answer: [Auto hide bootstrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528442/auto-hide-bootstrap-popover), but it does not seem to cover my exact scenario.

I initialize my popovers in the window load function like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#fileArea').popover({
    selector: '[rel=popover]'
  });
});
```

The trigger is a table row element. Normally when a user clicks a row, an item gets added to a queue. Rather than binding or unbinding a bunch of stuff, I set up two separate click handlers. One to handle table rows that do NOT have `rel="popover"` (and after executing the code, I then add the rel attribute!) and one to handle table rows that indeed have `rel="popover"`

This is all working dandy; the separate listeners successfully distinguish between the two types of clicks. Here's the code for showing a popup on elements with the valid rel attribute:

```
$('#fileArea').on('click', 'tbody [rel=popover]', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.popover({container: '#fileArea', placement: 'top auto', content:"This file has already been added to the queue."});
  setTimeout(function() {$this.popover('hide')},3000);
});
```

So, the popovers are already "initialized" (sort of... using the selector parameter with the #fileArea as the actual listener), and then when the popover method is called, the parameters being passed in create a successful popover. The setTimeout also works!

But then I discovered that if the user clicks AGAIN, the popover will not appear. I suspect it has to do with passing in parameters rather than just calling the void method or passing the string 'show'. Unfortunately, I need to pass parameters rather than use the data- attributes to store the content.

From console, if I select the row and then call `$el.popover('show')` on it, the popover appears again.

My current thinking is that I need to figure out if the row already has a popover configured on it (not just initialized, but configured). However, I don't know how to find that out in order to create a conditional. The faked code would look something like this:

```
$('#fileArea').on('click', 'tbody [rel=popover]', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if(/* popover is configured */) {
    $this.popover('show');
  } else {
  $this.popover({container: '#fileArea', placement: 'top auto', content:"This file has already been added to the queue."});
  }
  setTimeout(function() {$this.popover('hide')},3000);
});
```

Anybody have ideas for detecting if a popover is configured? Any alternative ways of accomplishing my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `.data()` value on the element when you initialize the popover:

```
$('#fileArea').on('click', 'tbody [rel=popover]', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.data("popoverInitialized")) {
    $this.popover('show');
  } else {
    $this.popover({container: '#fileArea', placement: 'top auto', content:"This file has already been added to the queue."});
    $this.data("popoverInitialized", true);
  }
  setTimeout(function() {$this.popover('hide')},3000);
});
```

**Or,** instead of hiding the popover, destroy it:

```
$('#fileArea').on('click', 'tbody [rel=popover]', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.popover({container: '#fileArea', placement: 'top auto', content:"This file has already been added to the queue."});
  setTimeout(function() {$this.popover('destroy')},3000);
});
```

**Or,** show the popover every time:

```
$('#fileArea').on('click', 'tbody [rel=popover]', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.popover({container: '#fileArea', placement: 'top auto', content:"This file has already been added to the queue."});
  $this.popover('show');
  setTimeout(function() {$this.popover('hide')},3000);
});
```

Comment: Full of ideas! I'll give some of those a try. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why the first solution isn't working, but alas it is not. HOWEVER, the "destroy" idea works great. I didn't try the third simply because I liked the first two options best. Thanks!